# is it possible to retrieve jsp site pagination data using PHP scraping?

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

i am trying to get pagination data using scraping. next page data are retrieved using on-click event, is it possible to retrieve?

this is my URL which i used for scraping :
http://www.esrb.org/ratings/search.jsp

this is the code of next page link :

```html
<input type="submit" onmousedown="restorePreEdits()" onclick="javascript:scrollPage('1');return false;" id="nextPage" value="&gt;&gt;" name="nextPage">
```

Comment: Find out what the click event does. Emulate it. Or use a scraping (or "automation") tool with JavaScript / client emulation.

Comment: have a look at target site to understand how it's working then try to automate same thing with at your end.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the website structure and the Javascript, you would notice that on each click on the next/prev button, the value of the offset input is adjusted from the form below, and then the form is submitted:

```
<form id="search" action="search.jsp" method="POST">
    .
    .
    .
    <input type="hidden" name="offset" value="50">
    .
    .
    .
</form>
```

All you need to do for scrapping information from the site is to simulate the submission of this form.

You can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code) on how to send POST requests using cURL and PHP.